# Why does empty view in layout file shows up on screen even though listview has items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a Listview to show some item and i have also used an empty view in case my adapter has no item for listview to show.Problem is when I go this this activity first it shows the empty view on the screen for a second and then loads the item and show them in listview.

My Activity `onCreate` looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.favorite_exams);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.favoriteExamsList);
        View empty = findViewById(R.id.favoriteExamsListEmptyView);
        list.setEmptyView(empty);
        new readingFavFileTask().execute(UtilityFuctions.FAV_EXAMS_FILE_NAME);
    }
```

My layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/favoriteExamsList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favoriteExamsListEmptyView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/favoriteExamsEmptyViewMessage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="You do not have any favorite Exams.Please add Exams using below button."
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favoriteExamsAdd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="onClickAddExams"
            android:text="Add Exams"
             >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How I Do make sure that empty view never shows up even for a second if we have data in our adapter.Should I attach the empty view to list later after checking the adapter or is thr any other way to do this?

Comment: The empty view is probably shown because the task doesn't quite finish setting the `ListView`'s adapter immediately. There is not much you can do unless you know exactly how much will the task take to execute.

Comment: If just do list.setEmptyView(empty) in my AsyncTask onPostExecute() method, wouldn't that help?

Comment: Yes, set the empty view after you first set the adapter in the `onPostExecute` of the task. That way the empty view will not appear the first time the task is executed. Of course this will mean that if the first time the task is run it takes 10 seconds to complete the user will not see the empty view in the screen during that time.

Comment: Ok let me try... and post the answer if it works and does not have any other flaws.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. I just need to apply Empty View `list.setEmptyView(empty)` in my AsyncTask onPostExecute() method after setting my adapter to list and it works perfectly.

Comment: I set it in `onActivityCreated` of my ListFragment after I `setListAdapter` using `getListView().setEmptyView(theEmptyView)`.  The call `setEmptyView` was definitely what I needed.  Thanks!