# Empty ListView even though item are added

Tags: android, listview

I've seen similiar problems, but none seemed exactly like mine and one I couldn't understand the answer so I'm hoping you might be able to help me. The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974152/why-does-empty-view-in-layout-file-shows-up-on-screen-even-though-listview-has-i) I'm refering to has somehow solved the problem with async tasks or something, but I'm not sure what that is.
I have the problem that I have a layout which has a TextView and below a ListView. The ListView and TextView are both dynamically updated. According to my method updating my list (and logging into LogCat) there are entries added.

> 12-23 18:31:03.185: D/FileHandle.readList(24083): Read 1 entries
>
> 12-23 18:31:03.185: D/MainActivity.updateList(24083): Updating List with 1 entries

But I only see the TextView and no list.
Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_path"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:longClickable="true" >
    </ListView>
       <!--android:id="@android:id/list" />-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for reading and updating the list:

```
private TextView mPathView;
private ListView mListView;
private String mPath;
private String mCurrentList;
private ArrayList<ListEntry> mList = new ArrayList<ListEntry>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private List<String> mListContent = new ArrayList<String>();


/**
 * Calls readList(mCurrentList)
 */
private void readList() {
    readList(mCurrentList);
}
/**
 * Reads items from list into mListContent
 * 
 * @param listName name of the list
 */
private void readList(String listName) {
    if (mCurrentList.compareToIgnoreCase(listName) != 0) {
        mPath += "/" + listName;
    }
    mCurrentList = listName;
    Log.d(TAG + ".readList", "Reading List " + listName);
    mList = FileHandle.readList(context, listName);
}
/**
 * Updates the list shown with the content of mListContent.
 */
private void updateList() {
    mListContent.clear();
    for (ListEntry e : mList) {
        mListContent.add(e.toString());
    }
    
    Log.d(TAG + ".updateList", "Updating List with " + mList.size() + " entries");
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The static methods in FileHandle are working. I tested the code before without a layout and without the TextView, just the plain ListView, and it worked.

And here is my onCreate method

```
/**
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    Log.d(TAG + ".onCreate", "Launching Activity");
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    
    MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
    mPathView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_path);
    mPath = mCurrentList = getString(R.string.rootlist);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ListEntry.init(getApplicationContext());
    FileHandle.init(getApplicationContext());
    
    
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListContent);
    
    mPathView.setText(mPath);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    
    readList();
    updateList();
  }
```

If anyone could give me a hint into the right direction it would be great!

[You can only the see TextView, not the List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXTAj.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root problem**
I don't believe it took me this long to notice... But you need to use `vertical` orientation:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

The ListView was off the screen the entire time.

---

**Other potential problem**
You need to pass the new Adapter to your ListView after populating `mAdapter` with `setAdapter()`.  `notifyDataSetChanged()` won't do what you want in this case.

---

Alternatively you can change the order of your code a little, in `onCreate()`:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListContent);

mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

readList();
updateList();
```

Next make `mListContent` to a List:

```
List<String> mListContent = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Finally change `updateList()`:

```
private void updateList() {
    mListContent.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
        mListContent.add(mList.get(i).toString());
    }

    Log.d(TAG + ".updateList", "Updating List with " + mList.size() + " entries");
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In this order, `notiftyDataSetChanged()` should work.

Comment: I updated the code and it still is the same result. LogCat shows one loaded entry, but it's still an empty list. I will update the original post and add a screenshot.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hadn't noticed that `mListContent` was an Array of Strings.

Comment: I changed it to a List, but it is still the same result. And my LogCat still shows 1 entry to be read. What else could it be? Now, let's assume my FileHandle could be wrong(even though it worked without the layout). I just don't want to miss anything as I really want this to get to work. Do you need more information or code?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you used your original code but called `mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` at the end of `updateList()`? If you still don't see anything with this approach it is possible that `FileHandle.readList()` returns one empty String...

Comment: Nothing happens, again, with:
`mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListContent);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`
And I did a LogCat output for `FileHandle.readList(context, listName);`
The output is: 
_12-24 00:01:16.045: D/MainActivity.readList(31275): Itemname: Test

12-24 00:01:16.045: D/MainActivity.readList(31275): Itemamount: 100 k_

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you! How could I be so blind. It worked without TextView because there was only the list and it was shown. But with the TextView the orientation was by default horizontal and the list was off the screen. Thanks for the help!